# Getting NotInTransactionException while querying neo4j index

Tags: neo4j

I am currently using neo4j 1.8.1 . I am getting NotInTransactionException , when I am querying the neo4j index to get some nodes.

Following  is a simple query , which i am executing  on neo4j

```
 if (graphDb.index().existsForNodes("NODEINDEX")) {
  IndexHits<Node> hits = graphDb.index().forNodes(NODEINDEX).query(query);
}
```

The following is stacktrace for the exception.

```
"message" : "Error fetching transaction for current thread",
"exception" : "NotInTransactionException",
"stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexConnectionBroker.getCurrentTransaction(IndexConnectionBroker.java:134)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexConnectionBroker.acquireReadOnlyResourceConnection(IndexConnectionBroker.java:84)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.getReadOnlyConnection(LuceneIndex.java:105)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:245)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:227)", "org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:238)", "com.uprr.netcontrol.starmap.neo4j.plugins.aggregate_node_status.NodeStatusHelper.getGraphNodes(NodeStatusHelper.java:39)",
```

I found the following in Neo4j api.

```
 private Transaction getCurrentTransaction() throws NotInTransactionException
{
    try
    {
        return transactionManager.getTransaction();
    }
    catch ( SystemException se )
    {
        throw new NotInTransactionException(
                "Error fetching transaction for current thread", se );
    }
}
```

Do we need to explicitly start a transaction for querying neo4j index?
Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Did you start a transaction started just before executing the query?

Comment: As this is a read transaction , I am not starting any transaction explicitly

Comment: regarding indices, my guess would be an explicit transaction is needed, though, even when only reading.

Comment: Rolf I think Mattias answer down there is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a theory: I don't know if this is only an issue with the code pasted here but the check:

```
if (graphDb.index().existsForNodes("NODEINDEX"))
```

checks for the index named "NODEINDEX", however the actual query

```
graphDb.index().forNodes(NODEINDEX).query(query);
```

checks for the index named whatever is in the constant NODEINDEX. Those two are probably not the same and so it tries to create that index for you and fails due to not being in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

if there isn't an existing appropriate index, I think it'll create one before returning it; this operation needs to be wrapped in a transaction.