# Using node index via Neo4j java api

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j documentation says that, read operations don't require to be in a transaction.

In the code below,

```
// graphDB and name variables defined somewhere.
graphDB.index().forNodex("indexKey").get("name", name);
```

"index", "forNodes" and even "get" functions of api require to be called in a transaction, how I know, they all begin with "assertInTransaction();" line.

What's the recommended usage of index? Should they be surrounded by a
   transaction all the time?

Comment: There is also another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521239/getting-notintransactionexception-while-querying-neo4j-index) relevant to this question, but I need a clarification to documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always needs a read transaction, the code is wrong if there is not one.